# Click button knowing part of its name

Tags: macos, button, applescript

I need to click a button that changes name from time to time: eg. ("Buy xxxx").

The first part "Buy" is fixed, the second one varies.

I've wrote this code but it doesn't work as expected, can you help me?

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Aycc"
    if button "Buy(.*)" of window 1 exists then
        click button "Buy(.*)" of window 1
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Untested!** Try to use the `every ... whose ...` clause to find the button:

```
set buyButtons to every button of window 1 whose name begins with "Buy"
if buyButtons ≠ {} then
    click (first item of buyButtons)
end if
```

Maybe you have to try *title* instead of *name*.

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg